# Getting "node\r: No such file or directory error" with swagon on osx

Tags: node.js, npm, yaml, swagger

I have installed swagon on OSX 10.11.1 using command "`sudo npm install -g swagon`"
It is giving me following error on giving **any** swagon command (For ex: `swagon -h`)

```
env: node\r: No such file or directory
```

How can I get it resolved?

Basically I am intending to generate project stub for a given yaml file, but  `swagon filename.yaml` command results in the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in my mac, here is how I fixed it, try fillowing command in terminal

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagon
vi index.js
```

In vi editor type

```
:set ff=unix
enter key
:x
enter key
```

This did the trick for me.

It appears to be the issue with fileformat, the format is dos specific, but after changing it to the unix it works fine